# How to extract certain frames from a .yuv video file and create a new video using FFmpeg, OpenCV and python?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, subprocess

I have a .yuv video file and a list containing some frame numbers. I need to make a new video with the frame numbers in the list and another video with the frame numbers that are not on the list. How can I do this using FFmpeg and subprocess module in python? I'm also using OpenCV in the program. I need the new videos in both .yuv and .avi formats.

Comment: Open the `yuv` file, use `seek` to get to the begging of each frame, read the frames, and write them to a new `yuv` file. Use FFmpeg to covert the new file from YUV to AVI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Open the YUV file in `rb` mode.
Open `inlist.yuv` and `notinlist.yuv` in `wb` mode.
Zero frame counter
Repeat until no more data in input file
    Read `framesize` bytes
    if framenumber in list:
        write to "inlist.yuv"
    else:
        write to "notinlist.yuv"
    Increment frame counter
Close files
```

As Rotem suggests, use `ffmpeg` to convert your 2 output files to AVI at the end.